# Positioning div's with media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, containers, response

I'm having trouble building the contact page of my portfolio site. Ideally I want the page to be the exact size of the users screen, so there is no scroll.

**[!! Drawn explanation of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikR1i.png)**

- When the screen is 1080p I want the page to be like drawing #1 (find the image link below)
- When the screen height is changing the black, red and blue containers should move together as a whole like drawing #2. Tough they are separate div's and of different dimensions. Then when the top part of the red and blue containers come close to the navigation bar (the green container) I would like to have them so that they stop 50px from the navigation bar and then the scroll re-appears so the red, blue and black containers do not interfere with the navigation bar..... Am I still making sense? :)
- The same goes for when the max-width changes like in drawing #3
- The thing is when the width reaches a certain pixel, let's say when the margin on the right is 50 pixels, the blue container should reposition itself beneath the red container, and once again the scroll should re-appear (if needed).

I've tried many ways to make it work, but haven't had any success yet. The screenshot in the comment section of this message as prove.

I hope I explained the issue I'm having in enough detail for someone to help me out. Thanks in advance!

**FIDDLE:**
https://jsfiddle.net/x36a3qh2/6/

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#navbar {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin-left: -50px;
}

#container_1 {
    width: 75px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 355px;
}

#container_2 {
    width: 75px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 355px;
}

.skyline {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 600px){
    #container_1 {
        top: 50px;
    }

    #container_2 {
        top: 50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Screenshot**  -   http://i.stack.imgur.com/gzJdx.png

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/x36a3qh2/8/ ?

Comment: The beginning kinda works, but the red, blue and black container still pass through the green container when the height of the screen gets around the 200 pixels.

Comment: This https://jsfiddle.net/x36a3qh2/9/?

Comment: Thanks a lot for thinking a long @NenadVracar , this comes closer to the solution. However, the containers shouldn't reduce in size when the height changes because they have content which will get squeezed. Also the skyline will still penetrate the navigation bar.